# Dynamically Calculate Sum on RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

[App Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1dmV.png)

I want to automatically get the sum of the items once added in the recycler view and at the same time get the sum of the items when the Quantity changes and when an item from the recyclerView is removed. I am new in Android, and I cannot think of any way to achieve this. I am thinking something like the code below, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
TextView ProductPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productPricelbl);
TextView QTY = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Quantity);

Int total;

private void GetTotal(){
   total += Integer.parseInt(ProductPrice.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(QTY .getText().toString())
}
```

I am using a custom adapter for my recycler view with the code below

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoVH>{

    ArrayList<ProductListViewModel> productList;
    Context mContext;

    public ListViewAdapter(ArrayList<ProductListViewModel> productList, Context context) {
        this.productList = productList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DemoVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row,parent,false);
        return new DemoVH(view).linkadapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DemoVH holder, int position) {
        final ProductListViewModel productListViewModel = productList.get(position);

        holder.Product_Name.setText(productListViewModel.getProductName());
        holder.Product_Barcode.setText(productListViewModel.getProductBarcode());
        holder.Product_Price.setText(productListViewModel.getProductPrice());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }
}

class DemoVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView Product_Name;
    TextView Product_Barcode;
    TextView Product_Price;
    TextView Product_QTY;
    ImageView addQTY;
    ImageView lessQTY;
    private ListViewAdapter myAdapter;
    int Quantity = 1;


    public DemoVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Product_Name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProductNameLbl);
        Product_Barcode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProductBarcodeLbl);
        Product_Price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProductPriceLbl);
        Product_QTY = itemView.findViewById(R.id.QTYLbl);
        addQTY = itemView.findViewById(R.id.AddQTYBtn);
        lessQTY = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lessQTYBtn);

        itemView.findViewById(R.id.RemoveBtn).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            myAdapter.productList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            myAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
        });


        addQTY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Quantity = Quantity+=1;
                Product_QTY.setText(String.valueOf(Quantity));
            }
        });

        lessQTY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(Quantity == 1){
                    Product_QTY.setText("1");
                }else{
                    Quantity = Quantity-=1;
                    Product_QTY.setText(String.valueOf(Quantity));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public DemoVH linkadapter(ListViewAdapter adapter){
        myAdapter = adapter;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a global variable in recycler view adapter and keep adding the amount in that variable in onBindViewHolder().
And when any item is increased or decreased or removed you can add or decrease that amount from that global variable.